# R plot matrixes and connect points of each line of second matrix

Tags: r, matrix, graph, plot

I have 2 matrices in R. One is called

```
j= matrix(c(1:8,1:8), nrow=2,ncol=8)
```

and the second:

```
B= matrix (c(Dav_Bou_k_med$r,Dav_Bou$r),nrow=2,ncol=8)
```

both `Dav_Bou_k_med$r` and `Dav_Bou$r` are matrices of `nrow=1` and and `ncol=8` so they are like this:

```
[1] 1.668 2.000 1.5 1.7 1.7 1.9 1.9 2.5
    etc.
```

I used this plot:

```
plot(j,B)
```

but what I get is the relevant points for every `1:8` of the first matrix (`j`) (2 points for every `1:8`, because I have two rows in `B`). What I want is to connect these points for every row in the `B` matrix in the plot. So, each of these points in the `B` matrix will be connected for each row (of `B`) and ideally with different colors. Is there any easy way to achieve that?

Comment: we can't test your code we don't have access to Dav_Bou_k_med$r and Dav_Bou$r

Comment: Dav_Bou_k_med$r and Dav_Bou$r are nothing more than two matrices of nrow=1 and ncol=8 of integers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to interpret exactly what you are looking for, but I imagine it's something like this?

```
j= matrix(c(1:8,1:8), nrow=2,ncol=8, byrow=TRUE)

fake_data <- sample(seq(1,3,0.2), 8, replace=TRUE)
more_fake_data <- sample(seq(1,3,0.2), 8, replace=TRUE)

B= matrix (c(fake_data, more_fake_data),nrow=2,ncol=8, byrow=TRUE)
plot(j, B)
lines(j[1,],B[1,])
lines(j[2,],B[2,], col="green")
```

[image: plot]